# ImageCropper.Forms throws: "Method not found

Tags: xamarin.forms

Ive followed the instructions. MediaPlugin is fully installed in all three projects. Now, I am calling this:

```
        new ImageCropper()
        {
           Success = (imageFile) =>
           {
               Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
               {
                   img.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(imageFile);
               });
           }
        }.Show(this);
```

But this throws the error:

```
method not found Plugin.Media.Abstractions.IMedia.TakePhotoAsync(Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions)'
```

Why is this happening? (IOS).

Comment: Did you solve that? I'm experiencing same issue here.

Comment: I did with the answer provided. I cant remeber exactly what, but i forgot one line of code from the sample. Just go thorugh the docs carefully again. it works eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS is required to have keys in your `Info.plist` for `NSCameraUsageDescription` and `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` in order to access the device's camera and photo/video library.

Such as :

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to the camera to take photos.</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to photos.</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to the photo gallery.</string>
```

If not works , you can share the sample project link here , I will check that .

Comment: I have all those keys in the info p list. it also doesnt work on android with the same error...

Comment: @user13397492 Okey , could you share the sample project link here ? I will check that .